# Piping sox output into aplay

Tags: linux, sox

I need to concat multiple mp3 files together then adjust there volume then play via aplay. I currently do this using the following 3 commands

```
sox file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.mp3 out1.wav
sox -v 0.5 out1.wav out2.wav
aplay -D plughw:1,0 out2.wav
```

This works correctly the only minor issue is it creates temporary files and I know it can be done by piping all these commands together somehow. Sort of like.

```
sox file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.mp3 | sox -v 0.5 | aplay -D plughw:1,0
```

But can't appear to get the piping to work (I am not really a linux user) Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Try: `aplay -D plughw:1,0 <(sox file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.mp3 - | sox -v 0.5 - -)`. `But can't appear to get the piping to work` Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Thx just tried and get
'aplay -D plughw:1,0 <(sox file1.mp3 file2.mp3 - | sox -v 0.5 - -)
sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of `-'
sox FAIL formats: can't determine type of  `-'
aplay: playback:2787: read error'

Comment: Read `man sox` and determine how to specify the type of output and input file to `sox` ;). There is also section about `-` (search `stdin` and `stdout).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell sox to send the output to stdout with the '-' option. However, from the sox manual, you have to specify an output type, such as wav. Then you have to tell aplay the type it is receiving as well. I'm not sure about how to pipe sox into sox then aplay but I've used `sox -v 0.75 example.wav -t wav - | aplay -D sysdefault:1 -t wav`